# Overleaf Box on Links too Short

Tags: hyperref, links, hyperlink

I have the following file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
 
    \chapter{ch1}
    \chapter{ch2}
    \chapter{ch3}

   
\end{document}
```

The table of contents has small boxes that overlap with the content, as shown in the following screen shot! How to fix this?

Here is the link to screenshot:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Can you add which engine you use, e.g. pdflatex or something else and which version of texlive you use (you can find both in the sidebar of your overleaf project). With pdflatex and up to date texlive22, I get https://i.imgur.com/UjJ74kD.png

Comment: Do you use the Overleaf viewer or the browser viewer (this setting can be found all the way down in the Overleaf menu on the left)? If you use the browser viewer, which browser is that?

Comment: @Marijn I use overleaf PDF viewer!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the compiler I use is pdfLatex and Tex Live version is 2022!

Comment: @Marijn in the Browser viewer in Brave and Chrome, it does not even show the red boxes!

Comment: Here is the link to the overleaf project! https://www.overleaf.com/read/sgwrrxddrjbs

Comment: This seems to be just a viewer issue. Your boxes look find when downloading the pdf from your overleaf project.

Comment: Yes i agree the overleaf viewer is at issue here. Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overlap with an external viewer (`okular` here):

[image]

The boxes are expected because it's the default of `hyperref` to show links. If you don't like it, you can issue `\hypersetup{colorlinks}`, which will avoid boxes and just color the links (by default red, but it can be changed).